# R: function to apply Anova over different subsets of one's dataset and collect output

Tags: r, dplyr, glm, anova, broom

A common task is to have to carry out a certain statistical analysis (like an anova, glm or mixed model) on different subsets of a dataset and combine the output tables with summary coefficients and p values in a single dataframe. I am looking though for a generic function that would take the type of model (e.g. `aov(...)` or `lm(...)` or `glm(...)` or `glmer(...)` ) and the particular output terms for which the coefficients and p values would have to be returned for each of the replicate analyses according to some grouping variable(s) in one's dataset.

Say if I have a dataframe in which I would like to carry out a certain analysis over the different levels of factor "replicate" in a dataframe `data` :

```
data(iris)
library(car)
data=data.frame()
for (i in 1:10) {data=rbind(data,cbind(replicate=i,iris))}
```

Using `broom+dplyr`, I could e.g. do an anova over each subsets of this dataframe (grouping by replicate) and keep the p values for term "Species" using

```
library(devtools)
install_github("dgrtwo/broom")
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

group_by(data, replicate) %>% do(tidy(Anova(aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = .),type="III"))) %>% filter(term=="Species")

Source: local data frame [10 x 6]
Groups: replicate [10]

   replicate    term    sumsq    df statistic      p.value
       (int)   (chr)    (dbl) (dbl)     (dbl)        (dbl)
1          1 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
2          2 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
3          3 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
4          4 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
5          5 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
6          6 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
7          7 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
8          8 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
9          9 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
10        10 Species 189.6364     2  362.6614 2.580311e-94
```

(I used 10 identical data subsets just as an example here)

I am looking though for a more generic function "`Anovabygroup`", which would take the dataframe, the grouping variable(s) (here `replicate`, but it could also be the combination of several grouping variables), the type of model to run (e.g. in this case `'aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = .)'`, but it could also be a lm, glm, lme, lmer or glmer model or any other model handled by `Anova()`) and the factors to return coefficients and p values for (maybe with option "all" to return everything) as arguments (any other options given could be passed on to the call to Anova). Would anyone know how to do this by any chance, using code similar to that used above, but generalised to take these arguments? Main thing I don't know how to do is to pass on the model (e.g. in this case `'aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = .)') as an argument and have it evaluated. Or does it perhaps already exist in some package? I think this could be useful as I always find myself coding this task over and over again...

PS I used github version of the broom package as the current CRAN version doesn't seem to handle Anova output well

Comment: Haven't you just created this function?  Just replace the formula with a variable and there you have it.

Comment: Well what I don't know how to do is pass on the model as an argument though. Say if I have an argument model="aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = .)", how can this be passed on (as it is text, but would have to be evaluated)? Sorry if my question to wrap this into a proper, more generic function is trivial but I am new to R...

Comment: Just passing on the formula would not be enough, as it would also be necessary to say whether you would like an aov, lm, glm, glmer, etc.... call to be made... So I think passing the whole call as a text argument could be easiest, but I don't know how to then have that evaluated...

Comment: Ah ok.  There are different ways to do it.  For example, look at the `lm` code to see how it handles the formula argument.  It would be enough to pass the model, becuase `Anova` is a generic that dispatches to different methods for the various functions it handles.  Edit:  you don't want to pass text - use a `quote`d expression or a formula argument.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - will look into it! If it's easy you could also consider to post it as an answer though :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Answer:

You can solve this by creating a wrapper function that parses text inputs. 
Here, I use `parse` and `eval`.

Ideally the function would also check the validity of the expression (`glm`,`lm`, etc) that is passed, but here is an example function to get you started.

It also lets you pass additional options to `Anova` as you requested:

```
anova_wrapper <- function(data, model_expression_as_string, grouping_variable,...) {
  f_wrap <- paste0('function(.) {',model_expression_as_string,'}') %>%    parse(text=.) %>% eval
  data %>% group_by_(grouping_variable) %>% 
     do(f_wrap(.) %>% Anova(...=...) %>% tidy) %>% return
}
```

### Example:

Using your example code (thank you for posting good code!):

```
data=data.frame()
for (i in 1:10) {data=rbind(data,cbind(replicate=i,iris))}

aov_model_expression_as_string = 'aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = .)'
lm_model_expression_as_string = 'lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length , data = .)'
grouping_variable = 'replicate'


data %>% 
    anova_wrapper(model_expression_as_string = aov_model_expression_as_string,
                  grouping_variable = grouping_variable,type="III")



    Source: local data frame [30 x 6]
    Groups: replicate [10]

    replicate        term      sumsq    df statistic       p.value
    (int)       (chr)      (dbl) (dbl)     (dbl)         (dbl)
    1          1 (Intercept) 1253.00180     1 4728.1630 1.134286e-113
    2          1     Species   63.21213     2  119.2645  1.669669e-31
    3          1   Residuals   38.95620   147        NA            NA
    4          2 (Intercept) 1253.00180     1 4728.1630 1.134286e-113
    5          2     Species   63.21213     2  119.2645  1.669669e-31
    6          2   Residuals   38.95620   147        NA            NA
    7          3 (Intercept) 1253.00180     1 4728.1630 1.134286e-113
    8          3     Species   63.21213     2  119.2645  1.669669e-31
    9          3   Residuals   38.95620   147        NA            NA
    10         4 (Intercept) 1253.00180     1 4728.1630 1.134286e-113
    ..       ...         ...        ...   ...       ...           ...
```

And using a `lm` instead of `aov` and different argument for `Anova`:

```
data %>% 
    anova_wrapper(model_expression_as_string = lm_model_expression_as_string,
                  grouping_variable = grouping_variable,type="III")



    replicate         term    sumsq    df statistic      p.value
    (int)        (chr)    (dbl) (dbl)     (dbl)        (dbl)
    1          1  Sepal.Width  8.19627     1  73.78707 1.163254e-14
    2          1 Petal.Length 84.42733     1 760.05861 5.847914e-60
    3          1    Residuals 16.32876   147        NA           NA
    4          2  Sepal.Width  8.19627     1  73.78707 1.163254e-14
    5          2 Petal.Length 84.42733     1 760.05861 5.847914e-60
    6          2    Residuals 16.32876   147        NA           NA
    7          3  Sepal.Width  8.19627     1  73.78707 1.163254e-14
    8          3 Petal.Length 84.42733     1 760.05861 5.847914e-60
    9          3    Residuals 16.32876   147        NA           NA
    10         4  Sepal.Width  8.19627     1  73.78707 1.163254e-14
    ..       ...          ...      ...   ...       ...          ...
```

I regularly these types of regressions/anovas repeatedly in monte carlo simulations, but I normally create a seperate function for each sort of analysis. There may be interest from the R community in a package that does these analyses repeatedly!